# C++11 prvalue id-expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 5.1 Primary Expressions it states:

> The type of [an id-expression] is the type of the identifier. The result is the entity denoted by the identifier. The result is an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, or data member and **a prvalue otherwise**.

What is an example of an id-expression that is a prvalue?

(That is, what is an example of an id-expression that refers to an entity that is not a function, not a variable and not a data member?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be an enumerator. ...

Comment: Thanks.  Could the statement be rewritten "The result is a prvalue if an enumerator or an lvalue otherwise"?  That is are the only entities that are prvalues as id-expressions enumerators?  It's kind of weird that the "catch all" otherwise set consists of only enumerators.

Comment: Enumerator is the only one I could think of. I could be missing something, of course.

Comment: @user1131467: there are other cases, for example if the id-expression refers to a constexpr in a context where a constant expression is needed, it will also yield a prvalue rather than an lvalue.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You are thinking of the lvalue-to-rvalue standard conversion.  To be precise, a glvalue that is eligble for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not a prvalue.  Also, there is a relationship between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and constant expressions, in that sometimes the conversion can disqualify an expression from being constant - but the conversion also takes place in non-constant expressions.

Comment: Couldn't `true` and `false` be pr-value id-expressions as well? From 5.1.1 `primary-expression` > `id-expression` > `unqualified-id` > `identifier`. From 2.10 `identifier` is just `an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits`. That seems to fit the requirements even though `true` and `false` are also literals

Comment: @jucestain Yes, it does. So do non-type template parameters.

Comment: @Justin There are more than one syntactic categories named "identifier". After phase of preprocessing, _keyword_ is distinguished from _identifier_ of _pp-token_, and it is not _identifier_ in _token_. Literals `true` and `false` are keywords rather than identifiers after preprocessing.